# how to remove integration problems when using delayed_job with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have been trying to integrate delayed_job in my ruby app. I have installed the gem successfully and now I want to run a task periodically after every 3-5 minutes . I am not sure how to use this technique using delayed_job . I know that I will have to use it under some function but still need some guidance. 
      I have a class userscontoller and I need to perform a task like if I want to create simple fields after every 3-5 min .

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end
```

I will have to use either delay or something else to run tasks after every 2 min like this:

```
@user = User.new(:start_at => 1.hours.since, :run_every => 9)
```

but this throws an error as it was just used as an assumption

Comment: It's not the task for delayed_job. It's the task for cron/whenever or something similar.

Comment: I just want to run a task every 2 min. So I came to know that Delayed_Job might be the right choice. Isn't it?

Comment: It isn't. Write your rake task and use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever), for example.